# What could possibly be causing program crash?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I have been working on a small program that creates ordered linked lists.  Apparently, there is a problem in my program (maybe), because whenever i execute this function, the program crashes with a return 255.

Essentially, the code is laid out like this:

```
struct listingRec{
    int mlsNum;
    double price;
    listingNode* next
};

//the calling function
void AddListings(listingRec*& topOfList)
{

int tempmls;
char ch;

  do{

      tempmls = VerifyMLS();

      if(ValidMLS(topOfList, tempmls)){

      //(the called function)
      InsertListing(topOfList, tempmls);


      }

      else{

      cout << endl << endl
           << "*****ERROR*****"
           << endl
           << "MLS# " << tempmls << " already exists."
           << endl << endl << endl; 

      }

      cout << endl
           << "Add another listing (Y/N)? : ";
      cin  >> ch;
      ch = toupper(ch);

  }while(ch == 'Y');

}
```

the crashing function, I think.

```
void InsertListing(listingRec*& topOfList, int theMLS)
{

    listingRec *current,
               *previous,
               *newNode;

    current = topOfList;
    previous = NULL;

    while((theMLS > current->mlsNum) && (current != NULL))
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    newNode = new (nothrow) listingRec;

    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Heap error - could not allocate memory" << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        if(previous == NULL)
        {
            newNode->next = current;
            topOfList = newNode;
        }
        else if(current == NULL)
        {
            previous->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            previous->next = newNode;
            newNode->next = current;

        }

        newNode->mlsNum = theMLS;
        newNode->price = VerifyPrice();

    }

}
```

Sorry if this question comes off a bit novice to (I'm sure) a lot of you.
The funny thing is I swear this program was working last night, but for some reason, it decided not to work today, and I'm totally stumped.  How could something work yesterday, but not today.

Even if you have no clue, if you can give me any tips or suggestions what might be causing the crash.. I would appreciate it greatly.. Thanks.

Comment: The best approach is to learn how to use a debugger. It will be very useful if you are going to be writing code like that.

Comment: Check your memory allocation. Looks like you allocate 256 blocks and all of them finished.

Comment: Methinks yo cuan start by reversing the order of these expressions: `while((theMLS > current->mlsNum) && (current != NULL))`. I.e. best to check for NULL before evaluating `current->mlsNum`; not after.

Comment: WhozCraig, thanks, you were right..
I'm just so discouraged I couldn't find that mistake on my own..But definitely lesson learned..I feel like a doofus

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents:

In the crashing function you have:

```
while((theMLS > current->mlsNum) && (current != NULL))
```

If there is the possibilty that `current == NULL`
than this line will crash, because it first evaluates `theMLS > current->mlsNum`.
So if switch the statements like:

```
while((current != NULL) && (theMLS > current->mlsNum))
```

it should work, because the second statement is not executed, when the first is false.

Furthermore I noticed, that you create an object with new but you'll never delete it. This shouldn't crash but leads to memory leaks.

```
newNode = new (nothrow) listingRec;
```

Comment: You were right, I was stuck on this problem for 3 hours...Who would've thought it was such a simple logic error (that I couldn't catch, ugh)..

Comment: Oh, and I'm not deleting the object because they are part of a linked list, if they need to get deleted, ill make sure to delete them and set pointers to null, no prob